# Having trouble creating a view in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to sql and am struggling to make a view. This works and pulls in the correct data I need as a table, but when I try it as a view I get the error:

> SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.

```
SELECT [Data_Collector_ID],
       [Batch_Info_ID],
       [AssetTag],
       [DateTimeStamp],
       [Dust_Collector_DP]
FROM (
    SELECT [Data_Collector_ID],
           [Batch_Info_ID],
           [AssetTag],
           [DateTimeStamp],
           [Dust_Collector_DP],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Batch_Info_ID] ORDER BY [DateTimeStamp] DESC) rn
    FROM [PLCLogging].[dbo].[Coater_Data_Collector]
) tmp
WHERE rn = 1 AND ([DateTimeStamp] > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
    OR rn = 2 AND ([DateTimeStamp] > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC
```

Any idea how to get this to work as a view?

I'm trying to pull in the two most recent values for each `Batch_Info_ID` over the past week. If I need to provide more details please let me know.

Comment: How did you try to make a view? It should be as easy as adding `CREATE VIEW xxx AS` in front of your query

Comment: try to use alternative tool in which that possible to do without efforts - https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/database-diagram.html

Comment: It's not clear what you did to get the error you say you got.   Please post the exact steps you followed.

Comment: I try to avoid `OR` whenever possible for performance reasons.  Looking at your `WHERE` clause I don't understand whay you even need to use `OR`.  Can't you just use:  `WHERE rn in (1,2) AND DateTimeStamp > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())` or even better:   `WHERE rn<3 AND DateTimeStamp > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())`

Comment: I right clicked on "Views" and selected "New View". I then copy/pasted the sql from my original post into the view and clicked execute. That's when I received the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3036b3d-0f61-4aec-a879-f6602e86515b/sql-server-2008-management-studios-why-do-i-get-sql-text-cannot-be-represented-in-the-grid-pane?forum=sqltools) talks about how complex queries cannot be interpreted by the view designer.

Open a new query window and copy and paste the following text and execute:

```
CREATE VIEW MyViewName
AS
    SELECT [Data_Collector_ID],
           [Batch_Info_ID],
           [AssetTag],
           [DateTimeStamp],
           [Dust_Collector_DP]
    FROM (
        SELECT [Data_Collector_ID],
               [Batch_Info_ID],
               [AssetTag],
               [DateTimeStamp],
               [Dust_Collector_DP],
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Batch_Info_ID] ORDER BY [DateTimeStamp] DESC) rn
        FROM [PLCLogging].[dbo].[Coater_Data_Collector]
    ) tmp
    WHERE rn = 1 AND ([DateTimeStamp] > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
        OR rn = 2 AND ([DateTimeStamp] > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
    ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC
```