# Show Unique values only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-server-2019

I am using SQL Server 2019 and looking for a way to show ONLY the latest value for each AOC based on its latest FW_Version. Here is my query I have so far but this shows everything:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dbo.Model.ModelName AS AOC,
    dbo.Chipset.Chipset,
    dbo.FormFactor.FormFactor AS Form_Factor,
    dbo.ProductRelease.ECO AS Release,
    dbo.ProductRelease.Date AS Release_Date,
    dbo.Intel.FWVersion AS FW_Version,
    dbo.Intel.ETRACKID
FROM
    dbo.Intel
        INNER JOIN dbo.ProductRelease ON dbo.Intel.ProductReleaseID = dbo.ProductRelease.ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Model ON dbo.ProductRelease.ModelID = dbo.Model.ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.FormFactor ON dbo.Model.FormFactorID = dbo.FormFactor.ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Chipset ON dbo.Intel.ControllerID = dbo.Chipset.ControllerID AND dbo.Intel.ChipsetID = dbo.Chipset.ID
ORDER BY 
    dbo.Model.ModelName, 
    dbo.Intel.FWVersion DESC, 
    dbo.ProductRelease.Date DESC
```

What I would like to show ONLY items marked in yellow... How can I make this happen?
[image]

Here is the list of my Tables which are joined based on their corresponding ID's

Table 1: Model

```
ID (Primary Key)
ModelName nvarchar(50)
FormFactorID int
```

Table 2: FormFactor

```
ID (Primary Key)
FormFactor nvarchar(15)
```

Table 3: ProductRelease

```
ID (Primary Key)
ModelID int
Date date
ECO nvarchar(10)
```

Table 4: Intel

```
ID (Primary Key)
ProductReleaseID int
ChipsetID int
FWVersion nvarchar(10)
ETRACKID nvarchar(15)
```

Table 5: Chipset

```
ID (Primary Key)
Chipsetnvarchar(20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        dbo.Model.ModelName AS AOC,
        dbo.Chipset.Chipset,
        dbo.FormFactor.FormFactor AS Form_Factor,
        dbo.ProductRelease.ECO AS Release,
        dbo.ProductRelease.Date AS Release_Date,
        dbo.Intel.FWVersion AS FW_Version,
        dbo.Intel.ETRACKID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.Model.ModelName ORDER BY dbo.ProductRelease.Date DESC) rn
    FROM
        dbo.Intel
        INNER JOIN dbo.ProductRelease ON dbo.Intel.ProductReleaseID = dbo.ProductRelease.ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Model ON dbo.ProductRelease.ModelID = dbo.Model.ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.FormFactor ON dbo.Model.FormFactorID = dbo.FormFactor.ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Chipset ON dbo.Intel.ControllerID = dbo.Chipset.ControllerID AND dbo.Intel.ChipsetID = dbo.Chipset.ID
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY AOC
```

Comment: Actually that worked in Query but if I try to apply that to the "Views" it will not let me. What I need is to be available in "Views". This is the error I am getting: "Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vIntelUnique, Line 23 [Batch Start Line 0]
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
"

Comment: @peka: just remove the `ORDER BY` if you want this in a view. You can `ORDER BY` later on when you'll select *from* the view.

Comment: Hmmm... I have removed `ORDER BY AOC` at the end but it's showing me Error "SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.". Removing  `ORDER BY dbo.ProductRelease.Date DESC ` would show error "The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY"

Comment: That's a problem with the view designer, not the query itself. You can read about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637077/10676716).

Comment: Thank you for the info